# Changing ispell to Spanish (Castellano) in Xubuntu

Tags: emacs, spelling, spanish

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04. I can't use a Spanish spell checker in AucTeX.  When I try changing it, I get the error shown below.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open emacs
2. Tools -> Spell checking -> Select Spanish dict
3. Try to spell-check (M-$) and you get Error: The file "/usr/lib/aspell/castellano" can not be opened for reading

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, in Ubuntu you need to install the dictionaries for aspell separately:

$ sudo apt-get install aspell-es